# Merging two video streams and saving as one file

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, webrtc

I'm writing chat application with video call using webRTC. I have two `MediaStream`s, remote and local and want to merge and save them as one file. So when opening a file, i shall see large video frame (remote stream) and little video frame at top right (local stream). Now I can record these two streams separately using RecordRTC. How can i merge them with nodejs? (no code because I don't know how it's done)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'merge them with nodejs'. Do you mean you would like to record a single video to match the frame-within-a-frame  you're seeing on the screen? There's nothing I'm aware of that you could use for this -- though I guess you could hack something with Canvas.

Comment: @SamDutton I mean exactly that. I thought about using canvas, but was not sure. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 3):

You can use FFmpeg with `-filter_complex`, here is a working and tested example using FFmpeg version N-62162-gec8789a:

```
ffmpeg -i main_video.mp4 -i in_picture.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0]scale=640x480[main_video]; [1:v:0]scale=240x180[in_picture];[main_video][in_picture]overlay=390:10" output.mp4
```

So, this command tells FFmpeg to read from two input files, `main_video.mp4` and `in_picture.mp4`, then it send some information to the `-filter_complex` flag...

The `-filter_complex` flag takes the `[0:v:0]` (first input, first video track) and scale this video to be 640x480px and it identifies the video as `[main_video]`, then, takes the `[1:v:0]` (second input, video track 0) and resize the video to 240x180px naming the video `[in_picture]`, then it merges both videos making an overlay of the second one at x=390 y=10.

Then it saves the output to `output.mp4`

It is that what you want?

UPDATE: I forgot to add, all you need in node is a module to run FFmpeg, there are plenty of those:
https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/ffmpeg